# how to use Runtime.getRuntime() to execute a .java file

Tags: java

How to invoke another java program by using Java `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`?

its been told for executing a program using java program we can use `Runtime.getRuntime()`.
Here is an example. I can open a notepad by using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe")`;

Can any one help me to execute a Java file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a java file like this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");
```

This is assuming that your environmental variable(`Path`) for `java` & `classpath` have already been set, else you need to set them too!

Comment: ...and the `PATH` environment variable to find `java`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can't execute directly a `.java` file. It needs to be compiled first. The compiling could be done using a System java compiler that can be obtained using `ToolProvider` and running with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String)`. A sample would be something like:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

        // creating a file, but you could load an existing one
        FileOutputStream javaFile = new FileOutputStream("Test.java");
        javaFile.write("public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, \"I'm here!\",\"Test\", 1);}}"
                .getBytes());

        // compiling it
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, System.out, System.err, "Test.java");

        // running it    
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");
    }

}
```